# Mistake on Python code or CNN architecture feature that I don't understad

Tags: python, keras, conv-neural-network

I'm newbie with Python and CNN.

I have found the following code in this [Github repository](https://github.com/hongweilibran/wmh_ibbmTum/blob/master/submission_sysu_.py):

```
### ----define U-net architecture--------------
def get_unet(img_shape = None):

        dim_ordering = 'tf'
        inputs = Input(shape = img_shape)
        concat_axis = -1
        ### the size of convolutional kernels is defined here    
        conv1 = Convolution2D(64, 5, 5, activation='relu', border_mode='same', dim_ordering=dim_ordering, name='conv1_1')(inputs)
        conv1 = Convolution2D(64, 5, 5, activation='relu', border_mode='same', dim_ordering=dim_ordering)(conv1)
        pool1 = MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2), dim_ordering=dim_ordering)(conv1)
        conv2 = Convolution2D(96, 3, 3, activation='relu', border_mode='same', dim_ordering=dim_ordering)(pool1)

        # The rest omitted by brevity
```

I don't understand this line:

```
conv1 = Convolution2D(64, 5, 5, activation='relu', border_mode='same', dim_ordering=dim_ordering)(conv1)
```

Why `conv1` is equal to `Convolution2D([...])(conv1)`?

They are using `conv1` at the begging and at the end on the sentence. Is a mistake?

Comment: In your expression conv1 is the output of Convolution2D(...)(conv1). The second (conv1) is the input which is the output of the Convolution2D(...)(inputs)

Comment: Thanks, but I don't understand you.

Comment: `conv1` is defined on the line above, so they are passing that into the function returned by `Convolution2D` and then changing the value of `conv1` to equal the new result. It would probably be better to use different variable names, but it works.

Comment: The right-hand-side of the `=` is evaluated first, so it's totally fine to do something with an existing object and then re-assign it on the left-hand-side

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not a mistake, you can even write

```
input = ...
net = Conv2d(...)(input)
net = Conv2d(...)(net)
net = Pool(...)(net)
...
```

Answer (score 1):

The reason why you think this is a mistake is that, up until this moment, you have used the so-called Sequential API in Keras.

What you are using here is called the Functional API. The latter is meant to allow more flexibility that the Sequential API.

You can read more about the Functional API and its applicability here: https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/keras/functional